# existing managed private endpoints not loading in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Failed to load resources of type "managedPrivateEndpoint". Some resources may not be shown.
Error: Internal error has occurred.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ITHl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can successfully deploy a private endpoint as long as it has the same properties as the one that already exists in the factory.  If a private endpoint already exists in a factory and you try to deploy an ARM template that contains a private endpoint with the same name but with modified properties, the deployment will fail.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery#best-practices-for-cicd